# how to iterate over request.body and update an object accordingly

Tags: javascript, loops, express, mongoose

Looking over [this MERN tutorial](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/the-mern-stack-tutorial-building-a-react-crud-application-from-start-to-finish-part-2-637f337e5d61=), with this "update" route.

```
todoRoutes.route('/update/:id').post(function(req, res) {
    Todo.findById(req.params.id, function(err, todo) {
        if (!todo)
            res.status(404).send("data is not found");
        else
            todo.todo_description = req.body.todo_description;
            todo.todo_responsible = req.body.todo_responsible;
            todo.todo_priority = req.body.todo_priority;
            todo.todo_completed = req.body.todo_completed;            todo.save().then(todo => {
                res.json('Todo updated!');
            })
            .catch(err => {
                res.status(400).send("Update not possible");
            });
    });
});
```

This is the schema used by the DB:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;let Todo = new Schema({
    todo_description: {
        type: String
    },
    todo_responsible: {
        type: String
    },
    todo_priority: {
        type: String
    },
    todo_completed: {
        type: Boolean
    }
});module.exports = mongoose.model('Todo', Todo);
```

I want to do the update in a loop, so a change in the schema will not make me change things in the route too.

- How can I do something like (using Python pseudo-code):

  ```
    for param in req.body:
        setattr(todo, param.name, param.value)
        # where param example might be an object with these 2 fields ('name', 'value')
  ```

  This is what I have so far:

  ```
    todoRoutes.route('/update/:id').post(function(req, res) {
        Todo.findById(req.params.id, function(err, todo) {
            if (!todo)
                res.status(404).send("Data is not found");
            else
                req.body.forEach(function (item) {
                    todo.setAttribute(req.body.getAttribute(item));
                });

                todo.save().then(todo => {
                    res.json('Item updated!');
                }).catch(err => {
                    res.status(400).send("Update not possible: " + err);
                });
        });
    });
  ```

Comment: You want req.body to be an array of objects?

Comment: @TheAlpha93 sort of. The 'add' route in that tutorial just creates an object using the `req.body` so I want to update accordingly, without specifying the fields of said object

Answer (score 1):

You could save the object in a single variable and then save it, only the changes that are submitted will be saved.

```js
/**
 * Update todo function
 */
// require todo model
const Todo = require("../models/todo");

async function updateTodo(req, res) {
    const { id } = req.params; // You get the todo id by parameter
    const todoData = req.body; // with this way you could save in a single variable

    try {
        const todoUpdated = await Todo.findByIdAndUpdate(id, todoData);
        if (!todoUpdated) {
            return res.status(404).send('Todo dont found');
        }

        return res.status(200).send('Todo updated successfully');
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(500).send(err);
    }
}

module.exports = {
    updateTodo
};
```

Comment: I took your answer and changed it a bit

Answer (score 0):

Based on @D4ITON answer, I tested this snippet, and it works:

```
todoRoutes.route('/update/:id').post(function(req, res) {
    Todo.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, function(err, todo) {
        todo.save().then(todo => {
            res.json('Item updated!');
        }).catch(err => {
            res.status(400).send("Update not possible: " + err);
        });
    });
});
```